# Updating tables on Postgres when AWS RDS causing connection freezes

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been using AWS for about 6 months now for some simple tasks like using EC2 to setup python scripts and cronjobs, updating tables on postgres. So far everything has been great but recently everything went nasty after the cronjobs that update tables increased upto 20, so there are multiple collisions of them simultaneously trying to connect to the database modify the tables(but no 2 scripts try to modify the same table at once). they started failing randomly and I am starting to see most of them fail, I need to reboot the aws rds instance for the cronjobs to work properly but again the same things repeat however. As you can see here, the db connections keep increasing and once I restart it, it's back to normal, same with the current activity sessions(wonder how it could be a float to be honest)

```
Error:
Exception: Unexpected exception type: ReadTimeout
```

I am wondering if the way I connect to the database is the problem or what? I can't even figure out if it's some measure from RDS to freeze any modifications to the tables because of many connection attempts. The thing is I am sure the script works, because when I stop all cronjobs, reboot the rds instance and run this script it works fine, but when I start all of them again, it's failing. Can someone please help me with some leads on how to figure this out?

Most of my scripts look pretty similar to the following, there are scripts that run once in a day and that runs once every 5 mins too

```
def get_daily_data(coin, start_date, time_period):
        return df

def main():
    coin1 = 'bitcoin'
    time_period = '1d'
    
    DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{USR}:{token}@{ENDPOINT}:{PORT}/{DBNAME}'
    engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    connection = engine.connect()    

    if connection is not None:
        old_btc_data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM daily_data", connection)
        start_date= str(old_btc_data['datetime'].iloc[-1].date() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))

        latest_data_btc = get_daily_data(coin1, start_date, time_period)

        if latest_data_btc is not None:
            try:
                latest_data_btc = latest_data_btc.reset_index()
                latest_data_btc['datetime'] = latest_data_btc['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)
                latest_data_btc = pd.concat([old_btc_data, latest_data_btc], ignore_index=True)
                latest_data_btc = latest_data_btc.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
                latest_data_btc = latest_data_btc.set_index('datetime')
                latest_data_btc.to_sql(daily_data, if_exists='replace', con=connection)
                print(f"Pushed BTC daily data to the database")
            except:
                print(f"BTC daily data to the database update FAILED!!!!!!")

        
        connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that the error is to related to creating a connection, somehow creating a connection using (`connection = engine.connect()`) is freezing any other modifications to the database table, it started working out for me by using the engine as the connection directly as follows:

```
connection = create_engine(DATABASE_URI, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
```

Edit: Much better to use sessions with psycopg2 cursors, exception handling would be easy.